# List<T> readonly with a private set

Tags: c#, .net, generics, c#-3.0

How can I expose a `List<T>` so that it is readonly, but can be set privately?

This doesn't work:

```
public List<string> myList {readonly get; private set; }
```

Even if you do:

```
public List<string> myList {get; private set; }
```

You can still do this:

```
myList.Add("TEST"); //This should not be allowed
```

I guess you could have:

```
public List<string> myList {get{ return otherList;}}
private List<string> otherList {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I think you are mixing concepts.

```
public List<string> myList {get; private set;}
```

*is* already "read-only".  That is, outside this class, nothing can set `myList` to a different instance of `List<string>`

However, if you want a readonly list as in "I don't want people to be able to modify the list *contents*", then you need to expose a `ReadOnlyCollection<string>`.  You can do this via:

```
private List<string> actualList = new List<string>();
public ReadOnlyCollection<string> myList
{
  get{ return actualList.AsReadOnly();}
}
```

Note that in the first code snippet, others can manipulate the List, but can not change what list you have.  In the second snippet, others will get a read-only list that they cannot modify.

Comment: great point. A lot of people miss the concept of reference types and setting the reference to readonly. +1

Comment: Even better would be to the ReadOnlyCollection as IList<string>.

Comment: +1.  Returning a public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection is better than using a "private set" on a public-property because it gives you compile-time-checking.  Meaning it will throw compile errors when using Add() or RemoveAt() on your read-only collection, whereas the "private set" will not.

Comment: @MikeTeeVee `private set;` doesn't cause `Add()` or `RemoteAt()` to throw compile-time errors *or* run-time errors. It's perfectly legitimate to add things to a List with a private setter from outside the class. This is why Philip recommended the second solution using `ReadOnlyCollection` to prevent external modification to list contents where such behavior is desired.

Comment: @Dan Please re-read my comment, as this is exactly the point I made.  Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: @MikeTeeVee I re-read it, but the last sentence still seems to imply that you expect the `private set` variation to fail at run-time, due to emphasis on compile-time checks done by `ReadOnlyCollection`. In any case, the answer is more than clear so if you understand it and I understand it then that's all that really matters. (p.s. the fact that I can reply to a 3-year-old comment and get a response within 15 minutes is easily one of the best attributes of StackOverflow's users).

Answer (score 11):

If you want readonly collection use [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx), not `List<T>`:

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<string> MyList { get; private set; }
```

Answer (score 11):

I prefer to use IEnumerable

```
private readonly List<string> _list = new List<string>();

public IEnumerable<string> Values // Adding is not allowed - only iteration
{
   get { return _list; }
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach except that it's flawed: MyClass m = new MyClass(); List<string> x = m.Values as List<string>; x.Add("test"); foreach (string s in m.Values) { Console.WriteLine(s); } //This allows me to add values to it just by casting.

Comment: Well, thats a hack :) You can also use reflection to add elements to inner collection. IEnumerable hides implementation from MyClass clients. Will you be sure that I'm not using LinkedList inside?

Comment: You can always reflect to find the collection type so i'll always be sure. If you're going to do it, do it right. Sure anyone can use reflection to "hack" the object to add items but there isn't much you can do about that. Practicing proper techniques and using the framework propertly is all you can do.

Comment: If you want to expose IEnumerable<string>, you should still implement it as _list.AsReadOnly(), to prevent the problem described by DustinDavis.  However I'd prefer to return the result as IList<string> (or possibly ICollection<string>) because this tells the user that the property won't be using lazy evaluation (yield statement).

Comment: 1) Trying to cast interface to some class - is incorrect usage of interface and you should kick one who do this 2) What's wrong with yield statement?

Comment: @DustinDavis, how is using reflection to set change internal collection more of a hack than casting to a type **NOT** provided by the API to modify it?

Comment: You're not properly exposing the types to your consumers. Exposing it as IEnumerable doesnt tell them that it's a ReadOnlyCollection. If casting to another type is hacking then you're saying going from ICollection<> to List<> is a hack. How is it different than IEnumerable<> to List<> ? It isn't.

Comment: It is a hack to cast from ICollection<T> to List<T> if the API provides an ICollection<T>.

Comment: This is a good answer. Once someone starts casting to a theoretically unbounded set of possible mutable collection types to circumvent your public interface, they are asking for trouble. They might try 20 different collection types and find one that works until you decide to use an iterator. Using `IEnumerable<T>` is a lightweight, correct solution.

Answer (score 10):

Return a ReadOnlyCollection, which implements IList<>

```
private List<string> myList;

public IList<string> MyList
{
  get{return myList.AsReadOnly();}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a collection called `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` - is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4):

You can use List's AsReadOnly() method to return a read-only wrapper.

Answer (score 4):

```
private List<string> my_list;

public ReadOnlyCollection<string> myList
{
    get { return my_list.AsReadOnly(); }
    private set { my_list = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    private List<string> _items = new List<string>();         

    public ReadOnlyCollection<string> Items

    {

        get { return _items.AsReadOnly(); }

        private set { _items = value }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way

```
public class MyClass
    {
        private List<string> _myList;
        public ReadOnlyCollection<string> PublicReadOnlyList { get { return _myList.AsReadOnly(); } }

        public MyClass()
        {
            _myList = new List<string>();
            _myList.Add("tesT");
            _myList.Add("tesT1");
            _myList.Add("tesT2");

            //(_myList.AsReadOnly() as List<string>).Add("test 5");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Mmm... I think you can just use PublicReadOnlyList with getter new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(_myList)

Answer (score 3):

In the .NET 4.5 framework you can expose only the [IReadOnlyList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385.aspx) interface.
Something like:

```
private List<string> _mylist;
public IReadOnlyList<string> myList { get {return _myList;} }
```

or if you want to prevent unwanted casting to IList

```
private List<string> _mylist;
public IReadOnlyList<string> myList { get {return new List<string>(_myList);} }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private List<string> myList;

public string this[int i]
{
    get { return myList[i]; }
    set { myList[i] = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a List.  Sounds like what you really want to expose is IEnumerable

```
public IEnumerable<string> myList { get; private set; }
```

Now users of the class can read the items but not chagnge the list.

Comment: flawed! you can cast it as List<> and add values: MyClass m = new MyClass();
            List<string> x = m.Values as List<string>;

            x.Add("test");

            foreach (string s in m.Values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }

Comment: Yes, you **CAN** do a lot of things.  Of course you could always set myList to something other than a List<T> in which case that code would break.  I usually don't worry about problems caused by people purposefully ignoring encapsulation.

Comment: you shouldn't have to worry about people "ignoring encapsulation". Encapsulation is encapsulation and being able to cast one type to another has nothing to do with encapsulation. If you're going to do it, do it right.

Comment: @DustinDavis, casting an exposed type to another type that you know the implementation actually used is the definition of breaking encapsulation.

Comment: Consumers cannot break encapsulation. Encapsulation is a design mechanism implemented by developers. Consumers consume the objects in anyway they need/are allowed to. If you have specific rules that require consumers only access items in a specific way then it's your job to do it properly, not just hope that they don't know what the underlying type is.

Comment: @DustinDavis, Consumers certainly can break encapsulation.  Them ignoring what your API provides won't hurt you in any way.  It's like if I sell you a car with a warranty and you go and replace the tires with huge doughnuts.  You can do it, but I won't guarantee the results.

Comment: Just came across this, from "Effective C# 50 Specific..." by Bill Wagner:  "Exposing the IEnumerable<T> interface in the List<T> is one example of this strategy.  The Machiavellian programmers out there can defeat that by guessing the type of the object that implements the interface and using a cast.  But programmers who go to that much work to create bugs get what they deserve."  pg 155

Answer (score 1):

You could also create your normal list, but expose it through a property of type IEnumerable

```
private List<int> _list = new List<int>();

public IEnumerable<int> publicCollection{
   get { return _list; }
}
```

Comment: flawed! you can cast it as List<> and add values: MyClass m = new MyClass(); List<string> x = m.Values as List<string>; x.Add("test"); foreach (string s in m.Values) { Console.WriteLine(s); }

Comment: Indeed - even _list.AsEnumerable() would be castable to List, to my surprise.

Comment: Anyone taking a dependency on being able to cast an `IEnumerable<T>` to a `List<T>` to would be foolish.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but nevertheless: I don't like using the `ReadOnlyCollection` wrapper because it still exposes all the methods for modifying the collection, which all throw a `NotSupportedException` when accessed in run-time. In other words, it implements the `IList` interface, but then violates this same contract in run-time.

To express that I am really exposing an immutable list, I usually resort to a custom `IIndexable` interface, which adds Length and an indexer to an `IEnumerable` (described in [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/collections/iindexable-read-only-list.aspx)). It is a wrapper as it should have been done in the first place IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't see this option mentioned yet:

```
private List<string> myList;

public List<string> MyList
{
    get { return myList.AsReadOnly().ToList(); }
}
```

This should allow you to expose a read-only List.

Comment: This is not good. First, you are creating a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` to wrap the list. This is sub-optimal because an instance of `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` implements the mutable `IList<T>` interface and throws at runtime if it is modified. However you then throw away that collection after copying all of its contents into a new `List<T>`, which will allow modification, although not of the original list. Also this code is misleading because it exposes a mutable member which is intended to be immutable but is actually an accidentally mutable copy.