# make List items readonly

Tags: c#, private, readonly, public

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List<T> readonly with a private set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749021/listt-readonly-with-a-private-set)

I have a class as:

```
public SomeClass{

        public List<Status> log { get; private set; }

        public enum Status
        {
            waitingForConnection,
            connected,
            receivingFile,
            doneReceivingFile
        }

        // later I initialize log and populate it...
       ///

}
```

so far it is easy to tell that I am just able to set a new log list from withing the class. How can I prevent users from editing items on the list. In other words I don't want users to be able to do something as:

```
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
//....
someClass.log[3] = \\different value
```

if I make the list log private then I will achieve this but I want to enable users to see the content of the log list but not to be able to edit items.

also I don't want to make the public enum Status private so that the user can see the status...

so how can I restrict users from editing the items from the list?

Comment: Check out the answer in this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749021/listt-readonly-with-a-private-set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) for this. Also on another note, remember that the readonly keyword does not truly make collections read only.

```
private List<Status> m_Log = new List<Status>();

public ReadOnlyCollection<Status> Log {
    get {
        return m_Log.AsReadOnly();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would love this, but it is NET4.5+.

Comment: `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` has been around since 2.0.

Answer (score 4):

Return a [List.AsReadOnly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Don't make your property `List<Status>`. Just implement an indexer property that doesn't have a setter.

```
class Log {
  private readonly List<Status> statuses;
  public Log(List<Status> items)
  {
     statuses = items;
  }
  public Status this[int i]
  {
      get { return statuses[i]; }
  }
}

public SomeClass
{
   public Log log { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: This does not prevent consumers from doing something like `instance.Log[0].SomeProperty = 10`, does it?

Answer (score 1):

How about making the log list private and having a public get() property?

Answer (score 0):

One option you have would be to have `SomeClass` inherit `IEnumerable<T>`.

This will cause you to fulfill the contract and implement a GetEnumerator method. Simply return the enumerator of your list. This can now be used to as a read only IEnumerable collection.

**Edit**
I was looking at this again, and realized you only need to do add a property getter:

```
IEnumerable<Status> StatusList
{
    foreach (Status item in log)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```