# list<T> property with private set

Tags: c#, list, private

I'd like to know if this:

```
private List<FixedTickProvider> minorTickProviders;
public List<FixedTickProvider> MinorTickProviders { get { return minorTickProviders; } }
```

is equivalent to this:

```
public List<FixedTickProvider> MinorTickProviders { get; private set; }
```

the thing is:  I've inherited the first piece of code, while I myself am more used to the second option. As Is was about to re-write the portion of code, I wondered if those two are exactly equivalent though.

please note that I am NOT talking about readonly Lists here. I am fully aware of the "readonly list" topic as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749021/listt-readonly-with-a-private-set) and my question is slightly different.

NB: I am almost sure I once read an article stating that the compiler would produce the exact same code from those two extracts but I can't find it any more, nor can I find a precise answer on this subject. So please enlighten me.

Comment: The code is functionally equivalent, as you are well aware. Are you asking about performance differences?

Comment: I'm not asking about anything in particular and would like to know about any difference, be it performance-wise or whatever. It is more of a "I'd like to know more on the subject" thing. Not an actual "issue" per say. So anything on the subject is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both pieces of code will achieve the same result

```
//here you are declaring a private field of class
private List<FixedTickProvider> minorTickProviders;
//and only exposing get to rest of the code
public List<FixedTickProvider> MinorTickProviders { get { return minorTickProviders; } }

//here you are declaring a public property which can only be set by the class which is declaring it
public List<FixedTickProvider> MinorTickProviders { get; private set; }
```

As far as IL is considered there will be slight difference

In case of separate field and property following IL will be generated
[image]

In case of single property without backing field

[image]

Comment: dumb question: just to be sure, IL = internal logic, right? (never seen the IL acronym before)

Comment: No, it means Intermediate Language. Every .Net code is compiled and converted to IL. It is not directly converted and stored as machine code. At runtime this IL is converted into machine code and executed

Comment: @David IL = Intermediate Language http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language.

Comment: ah, so that's the term  for this in english. Thanks, I had be looking for it as well :p

Answer (score 3):

In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented properties make property-declaration more concise when no additional logic is required in the property accessors. They also enable client code to create objects. When you declare a property, the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.
So, both will have same output......

Answer (score 0):

They achieve equivalent results, except that any code which assigns the value will be different between the two (the first will assign to the field, the second to the property), and so, of course, the generated IL will be slightly different also.

---

(Of course, in the property assignment case, it's quite likely that the method call and the eventual field assignment are simple enough to inline)