# Make list/collection of objects with public properties truly read-only

Tags: c#, immutable-collections

I have following problem.

Let's say there is a public Class1 defined like this:

```
public class Class1
{
     public string pr1 { get; set; }
     public string pr2 { get; set; }

     public Class1()
     {
     }
}
```

I'm not allowed to modify class definition - it used by other people and they need it written this way. And here comes trouble.

I need `static List<Class1> myStaticList` which can be modified only inside Class2 and everywhere else is truly read-only.
And by 'truly read-only' I mean user mustn't change anything including properties of list's elements.

Something like: `Class2.list[0].pr1="newValue"` called from outside of Class2 should be blocked.

`ReadOnlyCollection` don't do a job because user can still modified given element of a list,
so solution given here [List<T> readonly with a private set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749021/listt-readonly-with-a-private-set) doesn't satisfy my needs.

Basically I've found a lot of possible ways of making list/collection read-only (e.g. `IReadOnlyList`) but all of them left possibility of changing properties of given list element if they have public setter.

The only solution I've found is creating new class:

```
public class Class1ReadOnly : Class1
{
    public new string pr1{ get; private set; }
    public new string pr2{ get; private set; }
    public Class1ReadOnly(Class1 tmp)
    {
        pr1= tmp.pr1;
        pr2 = tmp.pr2;
    }
}
```

But I hoped two find better way since it seems to me kind of strange to define whole new class just because of one single read-only list

Thanks in advance for any clues.

Is this even possible to this different way?

---

Real-world context is like this:

In code we edit database and I want to have backup list of records which has been changed with their initial values. I want to have it static just to have possibility of restoring DB everywhere I want. Class1 contains all the values of single record of our DB so by `List<Class1>` I can keep all modified records and restore them if it is needed. And since it is backup it is essential to be read-only because unintended change can lead to the disaster.

Comment: Is that the complete definition of `Class1`? Does it implement an interface that exposes what you need? Does the collection *have to be* `List<Class1`> or can it be something else with the same functionality?

Comment: If class1 doesn't have too many properties and methods, perhaps you can wrap it with your own class, exposing the properties as readonly and blocking access to the methods that changes the class1 objects state. It's a dirty hack but should work.

Comment: Do you control instantiation of `Class1`?

Comment: if you have the code of `Class1` then you can by hand write the properties `readonly` like this  `public class Class1
{
     private string pr1;
     public readonly string PR1 { get{ return this.pr1;}}

     public Class1()
     {
     }
}`

Comment: Perhaps if you can provide some context around your "real world" use case, it might lead to a completely different solution than that indicated in your post

Comment: @jdphenix collection can be anything I only need it to be 'truly read-only' Class1 doesn't implement any interface. The are only properties and constructor. That is all.

Answer (score 2):

By "I'm not allowed to change it", do you mean that (as the question wording implies) you are not allowed to modify the values in the class? Or that you literally are not allowed to modify the class declaration itself? Also, if you are not allowed to modify the class declaration, what about the code that uses the class in collections? E.g. would a `List<Class1>` object be required to continue to be a `List<Class1>`, or could you replace the `Class1` type with something else?

Without more context, it is difficult to know for sure what is best in your case. However, one possible approach is for `Class1` to be replaced by an interface:

```
interface IClass1
{
    string str1 { get; }
    string str2 { get; }
}
```

Then declare `Class1` as implementing that interface, nested inside `Class2`:

```
class Class2
{
    private class Class1 : IClass1
    {
        public string str1 { get; set; }
        public string str2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now, using the techniques you've already seen for making the list itself read-only, you prevent any other code from replacing elements within the list (i.e. with some *other* implementation of the interface). And only `Class2` can successfully cast the implementation of the `IClass1` element in the list to `Class1` to gain access to the public setter for the properties.

If that doesn't address your concern, it would be helpful if you could be more specific about exactly what constraints exist for solving the problem.

Comment: I've edited my post I hope is better now. The main constrains is that we are using project which is managed by other team, and we should minimize impact we have on already existing classes.

Answer (score 2):

Given the circumstance you have your approach is one that works. You're using a solution that is the adapter pattern. It is *not strange* to do something like this.

> Adapter Pattern 
>   **Intent** 
>   Convert the interface of a class into another interface clients expect. 
>   - Design Patterns (ISBN 0-201-63361-2)

I would define such a class like this:

```
public interface IClass1 {
  string pr1 { get; }
  string pr2 { get; }
}

internal class Class1Adapter : IClass1 {
  public static Class1Adapter FromClass1(Class1 class1) {
    var pr1 = class1.pr1;
    var pr2 = class1.pr2;
    return new Class1Adapter {pr1 = pr1, pr2 = pr2};
  }

  public string pr1 { get; private set; }
  public string pr2 { get; private set; }
}
```

Why make the choices I did?

- internal class so I don't leak out to other assemblies. That way other teams can't use `Class1Adapter` unless you explicitly let it out.
- Implement a new interface `IClass1`. You say you are not able to change the definition of `Class1`, but if it wasn't an API breaking change... you might be able to pitch it to the other team. You could with the current definition change `Class1` to implement `IClass1` and with no other changes, you could in your code:

```csharp
var list = new ReadOnlyCollection<IClass1>(source); 

// ... and later, if attempted

list[0].pr1 = "I'm breaking you!";
```

Would produce:

> Property or indexer 'ConsoleApplication19.IClass1.pr1' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Answer (score 1):

How about **Protected** set?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

or you can override property setter.

:)

Comment: `protected` only helps if the class that's supposed to be able to access the member is a subclass. Likewise `override` (which only works for `virtual` members anyway). I'm a bit confused about what you're proposing; it would be helpful if you'd add some detail to your answer, showing in a code example what you mean.